# Adding specific values for inherited fields

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass, private, superclass

I am having some trouble with inheritance (Student here). I need to be able to utilize 1 inherited private field for each subclass I make. Obviously subclasses cannot have access to inherited fields however when a new object is created that inherited private field is a part of that object. For my purposes though each subclass needs to have it's own specific value for that inherited field. My first attempt looks something like this:

```
Public class A {

    private int x = 0;

    public A(int n) {

        x = n;
    }

    public int useX() {

        return x;
    }
}

Public class B Extends A {
    int n = 1;

    public B() {
        super(n);
    }

    useX(); // Return 1?
}

Public class C Extends A {
    int n = 2;

    public B() {
        super(n);
    }

    useX(); // Return 2?
}
```

However my professors tell me that I could also be using a setter method inside of my Super class to create that new field, and from there I am confused. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile (there's no `n` in `B` and `C`, and you can't do anything before `super`). If you fix that though, I think your approach is the correct one. Using a constructor is a good way to initialize the value without giving unnecessary unrestricted access to the value.

Comment: I just left off int in the declarations. I fixed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An ordinary Java Bean provides `public` *accessors* and *mutators* (aka *getters* and *setters*) for it's fields. However, you **could** provide a `protected` setter. Something like,

```
public class A {
    private int x = 0;

    public int getX() { // <-- the usual name.
        return x;
    }

    protected void setX(int x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

Then your subclasses can invoke that setter

```
public class B extends A {
    public B() {
        super();
        setX(1);
    }
}
```

And then `B.getX()` (or `B.useX()` if you **really** prefer) will return `1`.

Comment: `A` doesn't have a no-argument constructor though, so `super()` won't work without a parameter.

Comment: @resueman Good point. Removed the explicit constructor; certainly didn't need it for my example.

Comment: So a question that I have now is that if I were to setX(x) in the B class and setX(y) in the C class, would they change the value for A class or for their respective classes?

Comment: Only for their respective *instances*; the **class** wouldn't change in either case.